# Why in UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath is called before heightForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have breakpoints in both the two methods. The `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is always called before `heightForRowAtIndexPath`.
The problem is I have a logic code in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` that depends on the row height.
Currently, the row height I get inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is always 0.

Is there a way to let `heightForRowAtIndexPath` to be called before `cellForRowAtIndexPath`?
If not, how to call `heightForRowAtIndexPatch` explicitly in my code?

EDIT:

Here is my code for `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
let slideshowCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SlideShowCell") as! SlideShowTableViewCell
slideshowCell.delegate = self
slideshowCell.news = featuredNews
return slideshowCell
```

and here is my code for `heightForRowAtIndexPatch`:

```
let filterApplied = categoryNews.count != filteredCategoryNews.count   
if featuredNews.count == 0 || filterApplied
{
    return 0
}
else
{
    return 530
}
```

and when I set `featuredNews` to `slideshowCell.news`, I run this method in the `slideshowCell.news`'s `didSet` property observer:

```
private func populateSlideshowScrollView()
    {
        let imagesCount = CGFloat(slideshowNews.count)

        // set the scrollView's content size to the size of all the images
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: scrollView.frame.width * imagesCount, height: scrollView.frame.height)

        // Remove subviews of ScrollView before populating it with new images
        for subview in scrollView.subviews
        {
            subview.removeFromSuperview()
        }

        // populate the scrollView with images form the 'slideshowNews' property
        for i in 0..<slideshowNews.count
        {
            let imgView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: scrollView.frame.width * CGFloat(i),
                                                    y: scrollView.bounds.origin.y,
                                                    width: scrollView.frame.width,
                                                    height: scrollView.frame.height))
            imgView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
            imgView.clipsToBounds = true
            imgView.image = slideshowNews[i].image
            scrollView.addSubview(imgView)
        }

        // set scrollview to the first page from the right, only the first two times this method called.
        // After that the current page of page control should be in the correct position
        if numberOfRefresh < 2
        {
            scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: scrollView.frame.width * (imagesCount - 1), y: 0), animated: false)
            newsTitleLabel.text = slideshowNews.last?.title
            sourceLabel.text = slideshowNews.last?.source.name
            numberOfRefresh += 1
        }

        scrollToPage(page: pageControl.currentPage, animated: false) // to update scrollView's contentOffset
    }
```

The problem is that `scrollView.frame.height` will always return zero, because `heightForRowAtIndexPath` is not yet called at this point.

Comment: There should not be logic in `cellForRow` that depends on the cell height. What are you trying to do? You should [edit] your question (don't post comments) showing your relevant code (as text, no pictures).

Comment: Put the row height calculations in a separate function. Now you can call the row height from `heightForRowAtIndexPath` and `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. However, your code probably shouldn't be dependent on the cell height in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: I edit the question and post my code.

Comment: Override `layoutSubviews` in your cell class or use constraints to ensure things are positioned properly as the size of the cell changes.